# tsconfig does work only on single file in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

my tscongig.json does not work as expected. I simplified the situation to this structure in my project in VS Code:

```
-a.ts
-b.ts
-tsconfig.json
-def.d.ts
```

and the tsconfig contains:

```
"files": ["def.d.ts"]
```

Now when I'm working on a.ts, the intellisense is completing code from def.d.ts correctly. But when I switch to the b.ts, the definitions are missing. When I restart the VS Code with b.ts window active, the definitions became available on b.ts, but it is missing on a.ts. In other words, it only works on one file, until I restart whole studio with other file opened. Is it normal? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for ideas!

EDIT: My project is not a regular TS project. It is used to assist with writing many long scripts. The wanted situation is: *.ts files does not "see" each other, but intellisense is offering definitions from d.ts when editing .ts file. The current solution is reference to d.ts in every ts file, which works, but it's not so clean.

Comment: Why are you specifying a specific file to include? I would say that it's good to start with including all files (it does so without defining "files") and make an exclude array. If this does not suit you, you might want to include a.ts and b.ts in your files array as well.

Answer (score 0):

What I do instead of using files is use exclude instead. All .ts files not in exclude are processed by the intellisense:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "typings/main", //or typings/browser if you want
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    //etc, etc
]
```

That way you can exclude what intellisense has no business with and go with the rest.

In your case, you can just leave an empty exclude array, maybe with "node_modules" if you thing you'll be using NPM stuff in the future.